# gcl No matching signature for operator ~ for argument types: STRING. Supported signatures: ~(INT64)

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-logging

When I try the following query in google cloud log analytics

```
SELECT
   http_request.user_agent,count(*) as num
FROM
  `tympa-health-production.global._Default._AllLogs`
WHERE
  http_request.user_agent as string =~ "^google.*"
```

I get

```
No matching signature for operator ~ for argument types: STRING. Supported signatures: ~(INT64)
```

also tried

cast(http_request.user_agent as string) =~ "^google.*"

any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `=~`?  The BigQuery operators are here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators

Comment: Is the `tympa-health-production.global._Default._AllLogs` right? There are three `.` and the normal notation is `project.dataset.table`. Is the query working without the `WHERE`clause? Please try then `cast(http_request.user_agent as string) like "google.%" `

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a cloud Log Analytics query, I got the inquiry running with mine adding @Samuel recommendation:

```
SELECT http_request.user_agent,count(*) as num 
FROM `tympa-health-production.global._Default._AllLogs` 
WHERE cast(http_request.user_agent as string) like "google.%" Group by http_request.user_agent
```

But got null result possibly because there is nothing at my sink at the moment.